# Given the cylinder $(x-1)^2+y^2 \leq1$ and a sphere centred at $(0,0,0)$ with radius $2$, find the volume of the solid formed.

Tags: calculus, volume

I attempted this using cylindrical co-ordinates but I am not sure if my attempt is correct. This is what I have: 
equation of sphere : $x^2+y^2+z^2=4,$ cylindrical coordinates this is $z^2=4-r^2$ leading to: 
$$0.25V= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 r\sqrt{4-r^2} \,drd\vartheta$$

Comment: Use `$\pi$` for $\pi$ and use `$\sqrt{wxyz}$` for $\sqrt{wxyz}$.

Comment: This is called MathJax, a type of $\LaTeX$. It works in the title section too.

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly :)

Comment: It might help to include what steps you took to get your answer, since what's important when studying Mathematics is not so much the answers to questions, but the *reasons why* they are the answers. Again, please [edit] the question.